# How do I turn off the suggested videos that show up as thumbnails at the end of a YouTube video embedded with JW Player using angular?

Tags: angular, youtube, jwplayer

How to turn off recommendations in jwplayer ?

jwplayer('livevideo').setup({
      file: this.appState.selectedChannelSreamUrl,
      height: 400,
      autostart: true,
      width: 200,
      rel: 0,
    });

Answer (score 0):

The JW Player doesn’t have the ability to suppress or control YouTube functionality. It would need to be turned off on YouTube’s side.